# Count references to own ID in MySQL with Grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm running a query on posts in a database. If the post is a response to another post, it has a `parent_id` greater than zero otherwise zero.

To generate a report on posts, I use the following in my SELECT and then group by user.

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(parent_id = 0, 1, 0)) as 'NewPosts',
    SUM(IF(parent_id > 0, 1,0))  as 'Responses',
    COUNT(parent_id)             as 'TotalPosts',
FROM posts
GROUP BY user
```

Now I need to add a column that show's self responses by a user. Something like...

```
SUM(IF(parent_id IN id, 1, 0)) as 'SelfResponses'
```

Of course I know that is wrong but I hope it sends the idea across.

**Edit**: Data would look like :

```
User        Id        parent_id
Henry       12          0
Henry       24          12
Henry       32          16
Joseph      16          0
```

So in this case the output would be:

```
User         NewPosts        Responses     TotalPosts        SelfResponses
Henry          2                2             3                    1
Joseph         1                0             1                    0
```

Comment: Pl posy your table structure. You need a self join to find response for response for the post.

Comment: please post some sample data from this table `posts` and desired output.

Comment: It shouldn't be `2` new post for Henry it should be `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming for response the parentId is the postId for the response then you can achieve this by the following way

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
   a.user,
   SUM(IF(a.parent_id = 0, 1, 0)) as 'NewPosts',
   SUM(IF(a.parent_id > 0, 1,0))  as 'Responses',
   COUNT(a.parent_id)             as 'TotalPosts',
   SUM(IF(a.user = b.user, 1, 0)) as 'SelfResponses'
FROM 
  Table1 a
LEFT JOIN
  Table1 b
ON 
  a.parent_id = b.id
GROUP BY 
  a.user
```

**Results**:

```
|   USER | NEWPOSTS | RESPONSES | TOTALPOSTS | SELFRESPONSES |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  Henry |        1 |         2 |          3 |             1 |
| Joseph |        1 |         0 |          1 |             0 |
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1495/5)**

Hope this helps

Comment: Could you also tell me if it is better to do a `SUM(IF(parent_id IN SELECT id FROM posts WHERE ...` or a self join ?

Comment: And shouldn't that be a `LEFT JOIN` ?

Comment: I would prefer going for join rather than inner query as for each valid record the inner query will be executed, so by seeing from the end of performance it will be more expensive. It would be better if you check both the queries on your machine and check which one is better.